# Print a String in a specific index in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm facing a problem printing a String in a specific location on android studio, I tried using charAt() function but the app crashes (for example  tv.setText((res.charAt(1))); make it crash)

Comment: Please post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We clearly do not have enough information to solve such a problem

Comment: Please only use the [android-studio] tag for questions about the tool itself, not for general programming questions.

Comment: I cannot understand this: *printing a String in a specific location on android studio* and then you say *but the app crashes*

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to set the text of a test view based off a location inside of a list? thats what it sounds like anyway from the example you gave.

```
textView.setText(list.get(2);
```

That will display the test at index 2 in a list.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the text as the character at a specific location in the string, you have to convert the character to a string (using Character.toString()). For example:

```
tv.setText(Character.toString(res.charAt(1)));
```